# Как не выводить пустые поля в WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Как сделать чтобы поля группы записей в Wordpress, когда они не записаны их не выводить?

```
<?php

$my_posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'category_name'    => 'experts',
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'include'     => array(),
    'exclude'     => array(),
    'meta_key'    => '',
    'meta_value'  =>'',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'suppress_filters' => true, // подавление работы фильтров изменения SQL запроса
) );

foreach( $my_posts as $post ){
    setup_postdata( $post );
    
    ?>

    <div class="experts_item">

        <div class="experts_name">

            <p class="name"><?php the_field("full__name"); ?></p>
            <p class="description_data"><?php the_field("academic__degree"); ?></p>

        </div>

        <div class="experts_data">

            <div class="data_items">

                <p class="title_data">Квалификация:</p>
                <p class="description_data"><?php the_field("qualification"); ?></p>

            </div>

            <div class="data_items">

                <p class="title_data">Направление деятельности:</p>
                <p class="description_data"><?php the_field("activities"); ?></p>

            </div>

            <div class="data_items">

                <p class="title_data">Номер аттестата</p>
                <p class="description_data"><?php the_field("certificate__num"); ?></p>

            </div>

            <div class="data_items">

                <p class="title_data">Период действия:</p>
                <p class="description_data"><?php the_field("issue__date"); ?> - <?php the_field("expiration__date"); ?></p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
        

    <?php
    
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс
```

?>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверять а не пустое ли поле? `if ( get_field("academic__degree") )` и тп

Comment: Сделал, старые записи выводятся правильно. Но когда делаю новые, вроде создается item но уже все данные не выводятся.

Comment: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/Kaidos/pen/KKyWdQa?editors=1010) на код

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял Вашей дальнейшей проблемы, да и едва ли это имеет отношение к проверкам.